# Is there a java equivalent of vb on error/ resume next pattern?

Tags: java, vb.net, try-catch, resume

In VB, for error catching there is

```
Public Sub MySub()
    On Error GoTo Errr
    'do stuff
Errr:
    'handle error
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

which uses the magnificent Resume Next command.

In Java, you have a try catch block

```
try 
{
//some code
}
catch (Exception e)
{
//handle error
}
```

which seems to be equivalent to the VB error catching, but specifically without the Resume Next option, so Java just quits the entire code block after the error, instead of trying to run the rest of the code after the error. Is there any way to get the power of Resume Next in Java? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just put the code that you want to run regardless of any error after the catch block.

```
try {
    // stuff that could cause error
} catch(Exception e) {
    // handle error
}

// do stuff
```

If you're going to throw an exception from the catch block but you still want the "do stuff" code to run, you can put it in a finally block like this:

```
try {
    // stuff that could cause error
} catch(Exception e) {
    // throw exception here
} finally {
  // do stuff that will run even when the exception is thrown
}
```

Comment: This is not good for me. Putting code at the end or in a finally block assumes I know which code made the error, ie, it assumes I know the remaining code to be run at the end or in the finally block, which is not the case. Also, it will only trigger once, rather than for every error as Resume Next does. Thanks for the quick response, though.

Comment: The `on error resume next` just says to continue with the next line in the case of an error. If you're not sure what happened and you just want to continue with the next line, regardless of what line caused an error, then you apparently want to just ignore errors? It's hard to handle an exception correctly if you don't know what caused it, so just continuing on seems ill advised. You can do this by wrapping each line with a try/catch block and just having an empty catch that swallows the exception but I would advise against this since you should probably do something if an exception occurs.

Comment: I am currently doing just that, wrapping each line with a try catch block. So I should be more specific, it is SQL code; lots of table adds and drops. For my purposes, I don't need to handle the error, I just need a printout of the exception and for it to continue to try and add and drop more tables.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent in Java, to VB resume statements; in VB depending on the error case, you can choose to resume at a particular label within your code, in order to re-run the code after fixing the error, similar to a goto statement; this is not possible in java, except when you're inside a loop, then you can use the continue to a defined label block.